# Is definable partition choice equivalent to axiom of choice over ZF?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The principle that every parameter free definable set admits a choice function has been found to be equivalent to full AC over the rest of axioms of ZF (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4314897/is-choice-over-definable-sets-equivalent-to-ac/4314918#4314918))! However, I'll try here to present a version of this principle but in a different way, and the question is if the new presentation would also be haunted by a kind of the same argument in the original version.

**Definable partition Choice:** if $\phi$ is a formula in which only the symbol $``y"$ occurs free, then:
$$\forall X: \\X=\{y \mid \phi\} \land \\\forall y \in X \, \forall z \in X \,(x \neq y \to y \cap z =\emptyset) \to \\\exists f (f:X \setminus \{\emptyset\} \to \bigcup X, \forall x \,(f(x) \in x))$$

In English: every parameter free definable family of pairwise disjoint sets, admits a choice function.

> Is this principle also equivalent to AC, over the rest of axioms of ZF?

Comment: I assume you mean $\forall y \in X \forall z \in X (y \neq z \to y \cap z = \emptyset)$

Comment: @MarkSaving Yes! I've corrected it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If choice fails, let $\alpha$ be the least such that $V_\alpha$ cannot be well-ordered. This is definable without parameters, of course. Now consider the family $\{\{a\}\times a\mid a\subseteq V_\alpha\}$. Again, definable, since $\alpha$ was definable.

Easily, any two elements in the family are pairwise disjoint, so by definable partition choice, it admits a choice function. But this choice function translates to a choice function from $V_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal P(V_\alpha)$, which means that $V_\alpha$ *can* be well-ordered after all.

Comment: Nice! I think we can also estalish the same result if we take $\alpha$ to be the least such that $V_\alpha$ do not admit a choice function!

Comment: That would be about the same. Yes.